# LP with a linear cost function $c^Tx$: Prove optimal value is $-\infty$ or there exist some $v \in P$ such that $c^Tv \le c^Tx$ for all $x \in P$

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Suppose I have a LP with a linear cost function $c^Tx$, where $P=\{x \in \mathbb R^n : Ax \ge b\}$ is the polyhedron I want to minimize over.

How do I see that either the problem is unbounded, that is the optimal value is $-\infty$ or there exist some $v \in P$ such that $c^Tv \le c^Tx$ for all $x \in P$ ($v$ is a optimal solution with optimal value $c^Tv$).

Why is it not possible to have a case similar to: minimize $1/x$ for $x \ge 1$, where the optimal value is not $-\infty$ neither does a optimal solution exist. I know $1/x$ is not a linear cost function, but I'm just making an example here.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If $P$  is bounded the solution must be achieved on the boundary. The solution exists because $P$ is compact and $c^Tx$ is continuous. The solution must be on the boundary because of linearity of $c^TX$. This is trivial. Let me skip the proof. If $P$ is unbounded and exists such $x\in P $ such that $c^Tx < 0$ and $kx\in P$ for all $k>1$ then of course the  optimal value will be on $-\infty$.  The difference with $1/x$ is that this function itself is convex and bounded even on unbounded set $[1,\infty)$.

Of course it might happen that $P$ is unbounded while the optimal value is finite. Then the solution is achieved on the boundary anyway . 
Example: $\min x$ for $x\ge 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The solution must be on boundary, because we can always find a vector in some direction such that $c^Tx$ is growing in that direction (correct me if I'm wrong). What if $P$ is unbounded and there doesn't exist $x$ such that $c^Tx < 0$ - is this possible ?

Have you read "Introduction to Linear Optimization" by Bertsimas and Tsitsiklis ? I can't the solution to my question anywhere in this book. Have you seen the solution in the book somewhere ? I guess my question is pretty important and can't be skipped ?

Comment: I will add the case you are asking about in my answer.

Comment: Just to be perfectly sure, when you are saying boundary, you mean at least one of the constraints $a_i^T x = b_i$ is active ?

Comment: Yes that whAt I mean